# How to store a row from CSV file?

Tags: csv, python-3.x

In my CSV file I have 5 lines describing the file. I need to store the third line but ignoring the rest. I've managed to write a code that ignores all the description headers but how can I store just the one line? 
I wrote this code to ignore all description headers

```
for row in range(6):
       csvfile.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the 8th line which will be the 3rd line after the five header lines i.e the 8th line or index 7:

```
from itertools import islice

line = next(islice(csvfile, 7, 8)) # start=index 7, end= index 8 so one line
```

You can also use [linecache.getline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline) to get a single line from a file but it is not the most efficient.

If you had a very large file the [itertools consume recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) might also be useful to skip n lines:

```
def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```